# Can I link one list to multiple Word Templates for the purpose of Mail Merge?

Tags: custom-list

I have to find a way to merge one list to multiple word templates for the purpose of mail merging. I would like to have one column in the list determine which template will be populated.

All of the solutions that I have researched either involve exporting the list first to excel and then merging excel to word or merging one list to only one template.

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box way to use a SharePoint list as a direct source for a mail merge. Export the list to Excel and use it for the merge. In the Word merge template use the tools available to filter the source data by the column that specifies the template.

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty cool work around which will satisfy the requirements while avoiding excel.

I will simply create a custom list with my fields and include one dropdown field just for the template type. I will also create a custom workflow which will basically email the users the desired template with the information already populated. All the user will have to do is copy and paste the text in Microsoft Word. There will be an IF statement in my workflow for every type of document template I have which will send an email for each individually depending on what is selected.

Comment: OP wanted to avoid using Excel. Good workaround to this.